# why are we getting OAuthException,"code: 1 error?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, reporting

without any changes being made in our app we suddenly could not download any api reports and we are getting 500HTTP Internal Server Error, including this error in the devilry files:
"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}

I've open a bug but no one responded.

Comment: What's the URL of the bug report?

Comment: hi, we made a few changes in our code, i think something has change in Facebook side.. anyway our developers fixed this issue, thanks.